# Div background image wont show on mobiles

Tags: html, ios, css, image, background

I have a div class with a background image set. It displays ok on pc browsers but it wont show the image on mobile browser(i have tried android and ios)

the html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="headerdiv">
      <?php include '../inc/header.php';?>
   </div>
   <div id="wherewhen">
      <div id="when">
         <span class="wherewhen">WHEN IS IT?</span><br /> 
         <span class="wherewhentext">9TH/10TH FEBUARY 2014</span>
  </div>
  <div id="where">
         <span class="wherewhen">WHERE IS IT?</span><br /> 
         <span class="wherewhentext">HOLIDAY INN, MILTON KEYNES, ENGLAND</span>
  </div>
  <div id="what">
         <span class="wherewhen">WHAT IS IT?</span>
      </div>
  <div id="info">
         <span class="wherewhentext"> 
         A BACK IN THE DAY STYLE CONVENTION 
         FOR DISENFRANCHISED ARTISTS AND TATTOO FANS FED UP 
         WITH TODAY'S COMMERCIAL CORPORATE EXPOS.
         </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
  </div>
```

the css

```
html, body{
margin:0; 
padding:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background:#000000;
}

.wrapper{
width:80em;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
background:#000000;
overflow:hidden;
}

.poster{
float:left;
margin:-900px 0 0 910px;
width:370px;
min-height:600px;
background:#ffffff url('../images/siteimages/background.png');
}

#wherewhen{
background:#392da3;
width:600px;
margin:20px 20px 0 295px;
text-shadow: 2px -2px #000000;

}

#where{
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:20em;
}

#when{
float:right;
text-align:center;
width:15em;
}

#what{
width:20em;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#info{
width:30em;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Can anyone offer assistance here?

Thanks...

Comment: some real life code maybe. from there it's easy to think it goes off screen but .. ?

Comment: great, you should get some helps :)

Comment: I hope so!...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oki, `#poster` background could be in `#wrapper` with `background-attachement:fixed`.

Else from your code (#poster outside #wrapper )

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
/* your rules */
}
#poster  {
position:fixed;
z-index:0;
top:0;
left:0;
/* your rules */
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but still no image shows in mobile browsers! They just show the div with the background color!

Comment: Silly mistake on my part, i forgot to resize my image! After resize it works.

Comment: yeah problem solved, the accepted answer help me see my error. thanks again..................